# No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first

Tags: android, realm

I'm using Realm database for an Android application. Not sure why this happens but everytime I uninstall the app, first run always crashes in my Activity on:

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

Crash message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first
```

In my Application class i have this:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .name("mydb.realm")
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

       //...Crashlytics and other things...

    }
```

All future runs after this crash are ok. Any ideas?

Comment: Where did you call `Realm.getDefaultInstance();`? This method must be called only after you have called `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);`.

Comment: it probably has to do with the fact that `getFilesDir()` sometimes returns `null` in application's `onCreate()` on first run, and the Realm cannot initialize itself when that happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my problem. Realm had nothing to do with it. My custom application's onCreate was never called on first app run because of the allowBackup attribute in manifest. Setting it to false fixed the issue.